# Using Main Camera with transform.LookAt at a target but no rotation of camera

Tags: camera, unity-game-engine, game-physics

I am writing an app in Unity3d which is a runner game .Now when I jump the character up(move it in y direction) then the camera rotates because I am using

```
transform.LookAt(character)
```

1.the first image when the character is running properly

2.the second image is when the character jumps

[image: image with normal motion]
[image: image when the character jumps]

I want the camera to lookAt the character without rotating

Comment: you mean you want the camera to move upwards when the character jumps, or do you want it to just not rotate when he jumps?

Comment: I want it not to rotate when it jumps it should be like the way it is in first image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several solutions to this. Since you are manipulating directly the lookat direction through `transform.LookAt()`, you can simply change the target.

[LookAt](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html) method has an overload that let you specify the position of the target (`Vector3` instead of `Transform`).

You can than ignore the target's y coordinate and choose a fixed y value:

```
Vector3 lookAtPosition = character.transform.position;
lookAtPosition.y = fixedYPosition;
transform.LookAt(lookAtPosition);
```

Note that the solution above works only if the character stay always on the same plane (es. no more floor, stairs, etc..).

Comment: Thanks I tried this but It does not stops the camera from rotating while I make the character jump Up.Note that in the above two images the camera height remains same it just only rotates to LookAT the character while the character jumps

Comment: It rotates because the target y is changing value. If target's y remains the same it should note rotate. If target's y remains the same than you are modifying camera's y somewhere else.

Comment: Yes target y changes and I want that camera should not rotate while target Y is changing .I just want that camera should lookAt the character from behind at a certain height from it.Basically just like any endless runner game e.g temple run

Comment: target.y changes and in the code above is lookAtPosition.y. If you substitute it with a fixedYPosition than it should work.

Comment: Thanks! it works.Apart from that can you kindly guide(or give me a hint) how can I modify the script If my path changes to a path of lower height?Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Well, it depends on the effect you want to achieve. If you lock the y to a fixed value, the question is: when do you want the y to change?how should it change?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28308/discussion-between-hariszaman-and-heisenbug)